# private object not setting data

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to implement a LinkedList in Javascript. When i assign a value to my node it doesn't seem to store it when I use my getter. For example:

```
var Node =function() {

    var _data;
    var _next ={};
    var that = this;

    that.getData = function() {
        return _data;
    };

    that.setData = function(data) {
        that._data = data;
    };

    that.getNext = function() {
        return _next;
    };

    that.setNext = function(next) {
        that._next = next;
    };

    return that;

};
```

Will not work with:

```
var nodeObj = new Node();
nodeObj.setData("hello");
console.log(nodeObj.getData());
```

Comment: because you're assigning the value to `that._data`, but you're reading it from `_data`.

Comment: thanks i'm new with javascript and that is still confusing me a little bit.

Comment: What are you trying to build? When I use a Linked List, the operations performed on this list are usually that specific, that I stopped trying to implement any generic LL, or add any logic to the nodes. It's usually the code using the LL, that is also administering and modifying the Nodes in my implementations.

Comment: @Muffin, use [getters and setters](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/) of ES2015 for best practise

Answer (score 0):

`_data` is not the same as `that._data`, you must do this:

```
that.getData = function() {
    return that._data;
};
```

OR you could do this instead:

```
that.setData = function(data) {
    _data = data;
};
```

the benefit of the second approach being that you're simulating a private variable (because you cannot do nodeObj._data in the second case but you can in the first)

also `var that = this;` is unnecessary, you can simply do `this._data` in this case.

For your case here, you can assume that if you're calling a function like `yourObject.someFunction()`, then within `someFunction` the value of `this` equals `yourObject`. (And this isn't always true in javascript but since you're starting off you should think about it this way for now. If you pass a function to another function as a variable and then call it then this wouldn't be the case).